# How to execute a command in Java and redirect its output to a file

Tags: java, scala

Basically I want to do the equivalent of the following Scala code in Java.

```
command #> new java.io.File(outputFileName) !
```

Or the equivalent of the following in Python.

```
os.system(command + " > " + outputFileName)
```

I came up with the following code. Is it good enough? And even if it, is there any simpler way of doing it?

```
String [] Command = new String[...];
Command[0] = ...
Command[1] = ...
...

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (proc.getInputStream()));

String line;
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    pw.write(line);
pw.close();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?  `new java.io.File(outputFilename)` in Java wouldn't really "do" anything.  Files are just representations of a file, they might not exist or have any data in them.

Comment: That example is in Scala, not Java, and I've tested it. It works!

Comment: At least I don't know a better way doing it in java like in scala `("ls -l" #> new File("my.log")).!`

Comment: The first three lines can be simplified to `String[] command = {..., ...}`. Other than that, I think you'll be stuck with what you got. On an unrelated note, the Python code isn't strictly equivalent as it will break if `outputFileName` contains spaces (or other characters with special meaning to the shell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I came up with the following code. Is it good enough?

That's a subjective evaluation.  We don't perform those here.

> And even if it, is there any simpler way for it?

It would be much cleaner to use a [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec()`.  Among other things, `ProcessBuilder` has direct support for I/O redirection.  What you are trying to do might then look like this:

```
String [] command = new String[] { "command", "-arg1", "-arg2" };

Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command)
        .redirectOutput(new File(outputFileName))
        .start();
```

In addition to being shorter and cleaner, it is probably also more efficient, because the process's output will go directly to the specified file instead of having to be read into Java and then written back out.